# im geting [object Object] but i want to get text that in tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex, tags

can somebody say how to replace it ?

```js
function textFormat(value){
        value = value.replace(/\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}/g, <strong>{'$1'}</strong>);
        value = value.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, <i>{'$1'}</i>);
        value = value.replace(/~{2}(.*?)~{2}/g, <s>{'$1'}</s>);
        value = value.replace(/_{2}(.*?)_{2}/g, <u>{'$1'}</u>);
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: JSX is not an HTML string. It is syntax for `React.createElement(...args)` which returns an object. So you can't pass JSX to `replace` as if it were an HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you can show how you're getting the initial value that's being passed to the textFormat() function.

But in general it looks like the function expects a text string, but the value being passed to the function is an object.

[MDN docs: Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

The best approach here would probably be to adjust the code outside of the function, so that when the textFormat() function is called, the value it's called with is a text string instead of an object.

Or, a more versatile solution would be to add an input handler at the top of textFormat() to handle different kinds of input differently:

```
function textFormat(inVal){

    // check input type
    let value;
    if (typeof inVal === 'object') {
    
        // input is an object, so we'll turn the
        // object into a JSON string
        
        value = JSON.stringify(inVal);
        
    } else {    
    
        // input is not an object, so we'll assume
        // it's a string
        
        value = inVal;
    }

    value = value.replace(/\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}/g, <strong>{'$1'}</strong>);
    value = value.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, <i>{'$1'}</i>);
    value = value.replace(/~{2}(.*?)~{2}/g, <s>{'$1'}</s>);
    value = value.replace(/_{2}(.*?)_{2}/g, <u>{'$1'}</u>);
    return value;
    
}
```

Note, however, that with the latter solution if you input an object, the return value will be a JSON-ified string of that object (with the given string replacements performed). If you want to get back a modified object, then you'll have to turn the JSON string back into an object after the string.replace() lines.

You can do that with JSON.parse()